# Do any web browsers support HTTP Digest with alternative digest algorithms such as SHA-2

Tags: http, authentication, md5, sha, digest

I am looking to see do any web browsers currently support HTTP Digest using alternative digest algorithms such as SHA-2?

I know the proposed update to RFC-2617 is still in a draft state so just wanted to know if any browsers are pre-emptively already supporting the alternative digest algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of digest authentication, the MD5 weakness is not a concern. What is more important is a robust implementation of the nonce mechanism (and preferably the integrity checking, although only a few browsers support it) as it avoids replay and chosen plaintext attacks. Adding SHA to the mix doesn't help in any way.